# Looping through Deserialized XML using ForEach loop errors out

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I'm getting the following error when looping through deserialized xml using the foreach loop.

"Foreach loop cannot operate on variable of type 'Employeez' because 'Employeez' does not contain a public instance or extension definition of 'GetEnumerator'

Program.cs looks like this:

```html
{
    class Program : ParentClass
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DeSerializeEmp();

        }


        static void DeSerializeEmp()
        {

            string filePath = @"C:\Users\nabee\OneDrive\Desktop\XMLTest\";
            string fileName = @"myXmlFile.xml";


            XmlSerializer getEmps = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Employeez));

            using (XmlReader myXmlReader = XmlReader.Create(filePath + fileName))
            {
                Employeez allEmps = (Employeez)getEmps.Deserialize(myXmlReader);

                
                
                foreach (Employee myEmps in allEmps)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(myEmps.fullName);
                }
            }

            


        }
    }
}
```

and my Datastructure class looks like:

```html
{

    [XmlRoot("Employeez")]
    public class Employeez
    {
        [XmlElement("Employee")]
        public List<Employee> Employee
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }


    
    [XmlRoot("Employee")]
    public class Employee
    {

        [XmlElement("EmpId")]
        public int empId {get; set;}

        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string fullName { get; set; }

        /*[XmlElement("BirthDate")]
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }*/
    }

}
```

And XML looks like

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Employeez>
  <Employee>
<EmpId>12065</EmpId>
  <Name>Nabeel John</Name>
  <BirthDate>2021-02-16T21:59:23.7505798-05:00</BirthDate>
</Employee>
  <Employee>
<EmpId>12208</EmpId>
  <Name>Richard John</Name>
  <BirthDate>1986-02-16T21:59:23.7505798-05:00</BirthDate>
</Employee>
</Employeez>
```

Comment: Should be : foreach (Employee myEmps in allEmps.Employee)

Answer (score 0):

You deserialize your xml into class (good practice is to define type)

```
[XmlRoot("Employeez")]
public class Employeez
{
    [XmlElement("Employee", Type = typeof(Employee))]
    public List<Employee> Employee
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

so when you want to read employees, you can do it like :

```
foreach (Employee myEmps in allEmps.Employee)
{
   Console.WriteLine(myEmps.fullName);
}
```